# Redirect a Fragment to another Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mobile

I'm studying a lot about Kotlin, and I have a single project to make. So, I have some Fragments and one Activity.
All actions from left menu are working, ok. But in CalendarioFragment, I need to redirect to another Fragment when the user press a button. Now, I don't know how to do this. I am using Nav Graph, with navhost enabled in both.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calendarioFragment"
        android:name="com.example.aprimorandoconhecimentoss.ui.calendario.CalendarioFragment"
        android:label="fragment_calendario"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calendario"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_calendarioFragment_to_pdfFragment"
            app:destination="@id/pdfFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="false" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pdfFragment"
        android:name="com.example.aprimorandoconhecimentoss.ui.pdf.PdfFragment"
        android:label="fragment_pdf"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pdf"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>
</navigation>
```

My MainActivity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
        private lateinit var pdftela: FragmentPdfBinding
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            val navHostFragment =
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.calendarioFragment) as NavHostFragment
            val navCont = navHostFragment.navController
    
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)
    
            val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
            val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    
    
            // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
            // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
            appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
                setOf(
                    R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_calendario_academico
                ), drawerLayout
            )
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    
    
        }
    
        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
            return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
        }
    }
```

I tried to put supportFragmentManager on MainActivity, but this way, app crashes on init. Is there a way to redirect from Fragment locally to another Fragment?

```kotlin
class CalendarioFragment : Fragment() {
        
    private var _binding: FragmentCalendarioBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    var navc = NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendario, container, false)



        val listener = view?.setOnClickListener { view ->
            when (view?.id)  {
                R.id.botao_view1->{

                }
            }


        }

        return v
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect one fragment to another fragment without destroying previous fragment use this line of code :-

```
   findNavController.navigate((R.id.calendarioFragment)Yourfragment id in navigation graph)
```

Comment: I did this, but when I click on the button, the app crashes....

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity

```
var fragment: Fragment? = null

  fragment = CalendarioFragment()
       

        if (fragment != null) {
                val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.calendarioFragment, fragment)
                transaction.commit()
        }
```

Comment: I think it's not possible, because my button is on Fragment, not on Activity. When I get the click on button in my Fragment, I release a Toast and it works.

Comment: A question: how I instantiate a Button from my MainActivity? I tried this way you wrote and doesn't work.

Comment: _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false) add this code.

Comment: val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendario, container, false) delete this code

Comment: you have to do this but even if you do you can access the button on the activity not the button on the fragment

Comment: i put your code into binding structure correctly

Comment: I updated my code. can you try this

Comment: Yes, I tried. Not working. I'm doing in CalendarioFragment:

Comment: override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentCalendarioBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        
        
        binding.botaoView1.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.pdfVisualizador)

        }


        return binding.root
    }

Comment: It works! My mistake was in put binding instead of _bindind. Thanks for all!!!!